# Joining SQL query

Tags: oracle

i need help with left joining sql queries:

First query:

```
SELECT1
```

result:

```
WEEK Type First_month
21      12   50
21      14   4
```

Then i have next query(difference only in another month - the format result is otherwise the same):

```
 Select 2
```

result:

```
WEEK  Type Second_month
21      12   45
21      14   1
```

And I need the result to be like this (I can't connect the queries above):

| WEEK | Type | First_month | Second_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 12 | 50 | 45 |
| 21 | 14 | 4 | 1 |

Can anyone help me how to combine these two queries?

Comment: Something doesn't look right about your queries; if the 2nd query is for the 2nd month, why is the only difference on the end of your date range and not the start? Looks like that set of dates covers both months not just the second? Because on the face of it, I would simply change your second query to use conditional aggregation to get the first and second months results into two columns, since both ranges are covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use your current queries as CTEs and then simply join them. Something like this:

```
SQL> with
  2  first_query (week_kw, typ, first_month) as
  3    (select 21, 12, 50 from dual union all
  4     select 21, 14,  4 from dual
  5    ),
  6  second_query (week_kw, typ, second_month) as
  7    (select 21, 12, 45 from dual union all
  8     select 21, 14,  1 from dual
  9    )
 10  select a.week_kw, a.typ, a.first_month, b.second_month
 11  from first_query a join second_query b on a.week_kw = b.week_kw
 12                                        and a.typ = b.typ;

   WEEK_KW        TYP FIRST_MONTH SECOND_MONTH
---------- ---------- ----------- ------------
        21         12          50           45
        21         14           4            1

SQL>
```

I *hardcoded* results for both queries; in your case, you'd literally copy/paste those lengthy selects into the brackets, e.g.

```
with 
first_query (week_kw, typ, first_month) as
  (SELECT KW as Week_KW, typ,count (*) AS First_month
            FROM 
            (
    SELECT * 
            FROM
            (
      SELECT        leftDMC
      etc.
  ),
second_query (the same as the first one)
...
```

---

If there was yet another query, you'd create a new CTE and join it to the rest:

```
    ... ,
   third_query (week_kw, typ, second_month) as
     (select ...
     )  
   select a.week_kw, a.typ, a.first_month, b.second_month, c.third_month
   from first_query a join second_query b on a.week_kw = b.week_kw and a.typ = b.typ
                      join third_query  c on a.week_kw = c.week_kw and a.typ = c.typ
```

Comment: The 3rd query would make yet another CTE. You'd then just **join** it to the first two. I added an example, have a look.